# When using dispatcher.BeginInvoke, when/why do I need to call Dispatcher.Run?

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

Also, if I reuse this.dispatcher with another BeginInvoke, do I need "Dispatcher.Run" again?

```
 var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                this.dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                this.dispatcher .BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                       do something
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        onNotify(ex);
                    }
                }));
                Dispatcher.Run();
            });
            thread.Name = string.Format("{0} Hook Thread", this.GetType().Name);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
```

Comment: trying to run all calls of a certain type in a non-ui thread (but only on that one thread)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` adds a delegate on to the dispatcher's event queue.

The queue is only processed inside `Run()`.

[`Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run.aspx) is a blocking call that will execute forever (or until you call `InvokeShutdown()`).

If you call `BeginInvoke()` again, `Run()` will see the new delegate right away and execute it immediately.   (Or as soon as it's free)

Comment: gotcha, so if elsewhere in my code I have "dispatcher.BeginInvoke(do something else in the original thread)" it is ready to run it.